# How to kill process by name in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>>> os.system('adb shell pidof logcat')

750 4774

0
>>> os.system('adb shell ps | grep logcat')

root      750   1     8760   1720  __skb_recv 7f8f5a5edc S /system/bin/logcat

root      4774  4681  8708   1696  __skb_recv 7f98efeedc S logcat
```

There are 2 process of logcat.
How to kill both process Id : 750 4774

Answer (score 9):

you can try [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil)

```
import psutil

PROC_NAME = "abc.exe"

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    # check whether the process to kill name matches
    if proc.name() == PROC_NAME:
        proc.kill()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['taskkill.exe', '/IM', 'logcat'])
```

You might need to use `shell=True` if it can't find taskkill.exe.

Comment: i tried the above one. but it throwing error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Wait, if this is Windows code, why not just `taskkill.exe /IM logcat`?

Answer (score 0):

Introducing what I like to call `kill.py`

```py
import psutil

command_substring_to_purge = "app.py"
pids_to_kill = []
processes = psutil.process_iter(attrs=["pid", "cmdline"])

for process in processes:
    pid = process.info["pid"]
    for subcommands in process.info["cmdline"]:
        if command_substring_to_purge in subcommands:
            pids_to_kill.append(pid)
            break

for pid in pids_to_kill:
    process = psutil.Process(pid)
    process.terminate()
```

Note that to kill root programs you will need to run this as a root.
*With great power comes great responsibility.*